# How do I add axes x=0, y=0 and z=0 in a 3D plot in R?

Tags: r, 3d, axes

I wish to add like an `abline(a,b)` to a plot but for a 3-dimensional one using the rgl package.

Let's say for example this is the 3D plot:

```
set.seed(12444)
X = rnorm (1000, 50, 10)
Y = X*0.6+rnorm(length(X), 0, 10)
Z = Y*0.3+ +rnorm(length(X), 0, 10) 
# using rgl package 
library(rgl)
plot3d(Z, X, Y, col="red", size=3)
```

I would like to plot the axes x=0,y=0 and z=0 in the 3D plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks OK:

```
lines3d(x=0,y = 0:range(X)[2], z=0, col="red", size=3)
lines3d(x=range(Z)[1]:range(Z)[2], y=0, z=0, col="red", size=3)
lines3d(x=0,y=0, z=range(Y)[1]:range(Y)[2], col="red", size=3)
```

But this looks better(IMO):

```
lines3d(x=0,y = 0:range(X)[2], z=0, col="red", size=3)
lines3d(x=0:range(Z)[2], y=0, z=0, col="red", size=3)
lines3d(x=0,y=0, z=0:range(Y)[2], col="red", size=3)
```

Maybe change the color of the axes to 'blue'?

Comment: Thank you so much @DWin. It worked perfectly well :)) 

Only thing: My original plot is a Principal Component Analysis plot. So I adjusted the ranges of x, y and z as follows:

lines3d(x=0,y = -4:6, z=0, col="red", size=3)

lines3d(x=-4:6, y=0, z=0, col="red", size=3)

lines3d(x=0,y=0, z=-4:6, col="red", size=3)

My 3D plot has all axes x, y and z of ranges (-4 to 6). Thank you :)